# Data Source Design Pattern (Data Mapper) and Registry Vs. IdentityMaps

Tags: design-patterns

So I am learning data source design patterns and I was wondering about two things:

1- What is the difference between Registry and IdentityMap?

2- When using data mapper, where should the (Registry or IdentityMap) be placed? new package?, DomainLogic package? or Mapper package?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, the key difference between the [Registry](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) and [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) patterns is that the Identity Map's main responsibility is to ensure that an identifiable object is only loaded once. So if you had a customer with id 1, and different callers asked for customer 1, the Identity Map would ensure that they would all receive the same object reference. It prevents concurrency issues. In my experience, a Registry is used to centralise and control access to services.

For me, the Identity Map is very much a part of the mapping layer/package/context. Therefore I put it very close to my mappers. In practice, each of your mappers will want to share the same Identity Map for a given session/context.